# Clean up parent table rows that are no longer reference by any child

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, oracle12c, sql-delete

The obvious queries are

```
delete from in_pipe 
where id in (
    select id 
    from in_pipe
    where id not in 
        (select distinct inpipeid from out_pipe)
    fetch first 1000 rows only
)
```

or

```
delete from in_pipe
where id in (
    select i.id 
    from in_pipe i
    left join out_pipe o on o.inpipeid = i.id 
    where o.id is null
    fetch first 1000 rows only
)
```

There is `primary key index on in_pipe.id` and out_pipe.inpipeid has index `CREATE INDEX ix_outpipe_inpipeid ON out_pipe(inpipeid)`

Both of these queries would do the job and the execution plans look fine.

**BUT** I'm afraid about the performance of these queries once we get to production and tables have millions of rows (tens of millions). The performance of the clean up is not critical, but I'm afraid these queries would never finish.

Clean up should not effect performance of deletes/inserts from out_pipe or in_pipe, thus I would not use a trigger for this. I'd rather have this clean up done in the background during idle hours. It can (and should) be done little by little.

So I guess I'm looking for clever ideas...

Edit: I'm thinking browsing in_pipe ids in batches, starting for lowest and moving up, and checking for existence of the batch in out_pipe, until I reach the end and then start from the beginning again.

Comment: This is oracle, been a while, but can you do loops around your delete statement and delete top 1000 or so for each delete, but do it in loops?   I do this a lot in MS SQL, but not sure of syntax for oracle, but wanted to give suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Brad, that is what I'd do (hence the fetch first 1000 rows) but I'm afraid even a single loop of the query would have trouble finishing with millions of rows

Answer (score 2):

How about a two-and-a-half steps?

First step: table of `ID`s which aren't used:

```
create table not_used as
  select id from in_pipe
  minus
  select inpipeid from out_pipe;
```

A half of a step: index:

```
create index i1nu on not_used (id);
```

The second step: delete `ID`s which aren't used:

```
delete from in_pipe a
where exists (select null 
              from not_used n
              where n.id = a.id
             );
```

Comment: This looks quite promising! Bit heavier still than I would have hoped, but if this is run once a month for example, doable. I guess the question is: is doing insert to temp table via select id minus select inpipeid any faster/performant than doing a subquery/join?

Comment: I wouldn't know, but - if you try it and compare all options you gathered in this discussion - you'll probably find the *winner* and use it afterwards. Make sure you indexed columns involved into WHERE clauses, gather statistics, compare explain plans (without executing any code) and hope for the best. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `not exists`:

```
delete from in_pipe i
where not exists (
    select 1 from out_pipe o where o.inpipeid = i.id
)
```

Comment: Syntax is cleaner, but is there anything here that makes the query more performant? Execution plan looks somewhat the same as the others (join is the worst); this query has a full scan on primary key index (as do the others).

Comment: That's just one level of subquery, vs 2 in your original code. For performance, you want an index on `out_pipe(inpipeid )`, so the subquery executes quickly.

Comment: The only reason there is one more subquery in my original query is that they select first 1000 ids and delete those, instead of trying to delete everything in one go. The original queries could be rewritten to delete from by just leaving out the id select. The existence of the index you point out is already mentioned in the question. I doubt this query you have given would perform any better.